# Is it possible to run ChromiumOS as a session?

Tags: lightdm, chromium, session

Is it possible to install **ChromiumOS** within Ubuntu?

I am NOT looking for dual boot. I want to use as a session like *unity* or *gnome-shell*.

Please let me know if anyone has tried it.

Comment: @rafalcieslak : chrome os and chromium os are different,

Answer (score 5):

If you are using 64bit Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10
Just download and install [lightdm-login-chromeos](https://github.com/downloads/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos/lightdm-login-chromiumos_1.0_amd64.deb)

Note:it may show some warning messages during installation. Just ignore it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! While your answer is really helpful, we recomend including solutions within answers instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .xsession to start a session with full screen Chromium, but the entire OS (and user experience when you're logged in) is more than just an X session, and I think would be fairly difficult to re-create. Your best options are installing it as a dual-boot option, or running it in a full-screen virtual machine (the latter is very well documented - I'd check out http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/ for images and instructions).

For more questions, the folks (and sometimes Google employees) in #chromium on  irc.freenode.net are very helpful.